# Can't get rid of item in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, azure-devops

There's an item in our ASP.NET 5 project that no one in our team remembers creating -- see below.

[image]

Everytime I try to check in my code to Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) -- formerly VSO -- I keep seeing it. It's not on my computers and it's not on anyone else's computer either.

I can "exclude" it and be able to check in my code but I don't want to have to keep excluding it every time I need to check in something. I can't delete it either because it doesn't exist. When I right click it, the only thing I can do is "exclude" it from the check-in.

How do I get rid of it permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to the Changes window in Team Explorer, can you right click on the item and choose "Undo"?